# JPanel inside JPanel adds top padding

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grid-layout

I want to add a `CellPanel` which extends `JPanel` inside a `JPanel`. I do this, because I have buttons which remove the content from these `JPanels` and add other components. The problem is that the `FlowLayout` of the `JPanel`s doesn't position my `CellPanel` from top left corner. What can I do?

Here is the code where I'm having this problem:

```
    JFrame mazeFrame = new JFrame("Create and Play");
    mazeFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);           
    mazeFrame.setSize(640, 480);
    mazeFrame.setResizable(false);
    mazeFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);   
    mazeFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(rows,columns));//max(7,10)

    JPanel[] cellr = new JPanel[rows*columns];
    for(int i=0;i<rows*columns; i++){
        cellr[i] = new JPanel();
        cellr[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(mazeFrame.getWidth()/columns,mazeFrame.getHeight()/rows));
        mazeFrame.getContentPane().add(cellr[i]);
    }

   for(int i=0;i<rows*columns; i++){
        CellPanel cell = new CellPanel(wall.getImage());
        cell.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(mazeFrame.getWidth()/columns,mazeFrame.getHeight()/rows));
        cellr[i].add(cell);
    }
```

What it displays:
[image]

Comment: You could try and first add the CellPanel to your JPanel and then add the JPanel to the JFrame. You can also get rid of the setPrefferedSize calls as GridLayout should be able to determine the size automatically.

Comment: Two things, you could provide a `hgap` and `vgap` property to the `GridLayout` and don't use the frame size to try and calculate the size of your components, it includes the frame decorations

Comment: The problem is when I add the CellPanel to the JPanel. If I add the CellPanel directly to the mazeFrame it works fine. The problem I think is with the FlowLayout of the JPanel which does not align my CellPanel to top left corner.

Comment: Instead iof `mazeFrame.setSize(640, 480);` call `mazeFrame.pack();` after all components are added.  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research and I found a solution.

```
    JPanel[] cellr = new JPanel[rows*columns];
    for(int i=0;i<rows*columns; i++){
        cellr[i] = new JPanel();
        cellr[i].setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        mazeFrame.getContentPane().add(cellr[i]);
    }

   GridBagConstraints g = new GridBagConstraints();
   for(int i=0;i<rows*columns; i++){
        CellPanel cell = new CellPanel(wall.getImage());
        cell.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(mazeFrame.getWidth()/columns,mazeFrame.getHeight()/rows));
        g.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        g.weightx = 1;
        g.weighty = 1;
        cellr[i].add(cell,g);
    }
```